# How to send email from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet on Google Docs with tasks for a job that we are working on at work. What I am wanting it to do is to send the whole row to the intended recipient but I can only get it to send the info from the first column after the email address. Everything has a due date on it and I would like to get it to send a reminder when it gets close to that date but I do not know how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the code I have right now:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E, Column F, Column G
    var subject = "Email Test Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please ? :"Everything has a due date on it and I would like to get it to send a reminder when it gets close to that date"

Answer (score 0):

when you define your dataRange like this :

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
```

you read data from startRow **column 1** for **numRows** but only **2 columns** (the last value is 'width') so you could easily modify your script to get all the columns you want just by changing this last value.  Then using row[i].toString(), you will get your comma separated fields.

Then you might want to get a better presentation using HTML format to present data in a table for example but this is outside the point of your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you define a data range like this

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
```

you are taking the data from `A3:C5`

you can also refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getRange)

If you can post a sample spreadsheet as per the description of your problem, then it will be helpful for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This piece: `var message = row[1];` will only ever get the second element (index 1) in the array. You'll need to iterate through the row to get all the array elements.

```
var message = row[1];
message.concat(row[2]);
message.concat(row[3]);
```

And so on. Or you could build a loop.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

And to get the range, why do it the hard way? `sheet.getRange("A2:B3");`
That's the range you said you're trying to get in the comment above that line, although it is only 4 cells. `sheet.getRange("A2:G3")` would get two rows out to column G.
Of course, if you add rows to the sheet, you'd have to modify the code every time.

Instead, try this.

```
var bottomRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var rangeInA1 = "A2:G"+bottomRow;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(rangeInA1);
```