# How to send contents of a 'Form inside of a spreadsheet' to an email address?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is a simple question about 'Google Apps Script'.

**What I have done?**

Here I created a sheet with an associated script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIsQCs7TX83Y-TFMsnuOKUtkwQFRSCZ21h3E0VH7PBI/edit?usp=sharing

This sheet has email address at cell **A1**. When the script bound to this sheet is run (*Tools > Script editor* > Run), it successfully sends the contents of sheet to the email address stored at A1 cell. Currently, this script only takes the contents from B1 cell. I want to extend this functionality to a *Form inside of sheet*.

This is the associated [script](https://script.google.com/macros/d/MwxJoHhK-LPMUS5Z2YP1yRJ8MHtwhOX7t/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvEYi0EdWSsDzPmw7y_lhYtclBrukvI_kmKMeagkVWP9RECrqM8HgTtUmXO5n91mQzLHbLiJBpVvub2otoDxn6mo8FjgcZ3IcuYjI40AorPC_cuX4MFOah6Gla1JMeW9vMmMq2lKaIM):

```
function sendEmail() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) 
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending Email from a Spreadsheet Form";    
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

**What I am looking for?**

How to add a **form** in above sheet that would allow the user to enter some data from a drop-down list (say product name); and how to add a send **button** on the form, when this button is clicked, it will send an email with the form’s content (whatever user has selected from the drop-down list) to the email address already entered in sheet on cell at A1.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't see a clear question in your question, so please edit it to clarify. Otherwise, this question is doomed to be closed as "unclear what you're asking". If you haven't done so already, read over [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That's a bit better, but still not a clear question. (The only actual question in it is "What have I done?") What you've got is a specification - it lays out some requirements you want code to meet, expressed in terms of "I want..." and "I need..."  The problem with that is twofold: first, it's an incomplete spec; anyone who tries to give you code that does what you've asked will be likely to find that it's not exactly what you wanted, because there's "one more thing". Second, there's no programming _problem_ - what is the thing that you haven't been able to solve with your own best effort?

Comment: This is the script (https://script.google.com/macros/d/MwxJoHhK-LPMUS5Z2YP1yRJ8MHtwhOX7t/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvEYi0EdWSsDzPmw7y_lhYtclBrukvI_kmKMeagkVWP9RECrqM8HgTtUmXO5n91mQzLHbLiJBpVvub2otoDxn6mo8FjgcZ3IcuYjI40AorPC_cuX4MFOah6Gla1JMeW9vMmMq2lKaIM) as shown above. This JavaScript code only sends contents from a single cell of spreadsheet to an email address at A1, moreover, its get executed by the Run button provided on the toolbar of script editor.  --------  How to modify this code so that it takes contents  from the form's drop-down list, and gets executed by the Send button on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost answer: 
[How to send email from a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568061/how-to-send-email-from-a-spreadsheet)

Along with:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus?hl=en#drawings